# android ddms tool error specified

Tags: android, android-emulator, ddms

when i run the ddms tool in the tools directory i got this error"failed to get the adb version:cannot run program adb;create process error=2;the system cannot find file specified"

how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 4):

Right click on Compute than go to **properties -> advanced system settings -> environment variables -> in system variables** edit Path variable and add path of your adb.exe which is usually (sdk folder)/platform-tools.. thats how I solved it..

Answer (score 1):

Just add the environment variable 
I got my solution from here
http://myitsolution.info/?p=30

Answer (score 1):

My ddms ran ok until a few days when I updated NetBeans IDE. Then my ddms showed the same error. I'm not sure if the problem comes since the update because I didn't use ddms just after update.

Looking for information I tried to modify the environment variables but everything remained bad. Then I saw I had a adb file without extension with 0 kb in `\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` and I had the adb.exe as well. 
I deleted adb file (0 kb without extension) and ddms ran ok again.

Answer (score 0):

To fix, try to replace the adb file from the old SDK.